# Continuous Integration with Omnis Studio

Tags: rapid-prototyping

Is there any capability in Omnis Studio to use continuous integration? I have try third-party software but nothing is easy integrate.

Answer (score 2):

In Omnis Studio 8.1.6 you can use export to and import from json to write your library to text files.
I also suggest you take a look at omniscli (https://github.com/suransys/omniscli) which you can use to automate those steps. 
Then you can use git and jenkins for example to handle some typical ci tasks.
Omnis itself doesn’t provide all these tools but gives you the flexibility to use all 3rd party tools that matches your needs best.